# Using a VPN provider thoughts about security

Tags: dns, openvpn

If i use an a VPN provider that offers Open VPN would i still have to worry about my DNS requests possilby getting messed with and that i am getting forwarded to a malware hosting site or is this impossible if my system and Open VPN is correctly setup?

I guess it is a trust thing because i afaik i am using the VPN providers DNS servers and theoretically he could like without a VPN my ISP forward me where he wants to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the safety of your DNS queries, you should install [dnscrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/), a tool that encrypts your queries, and allows you to choose one of a number of DNS providers supporting the encryption and the change of ports. The two features(encryption and change of ports) are sufficient to allow you to avoid both well- and ill-meaning hijacking of your requests, as well as circumventing proxies, firewalls, and so on.

If you are using Windows or Mac, you will find the download page referenced in the link above, otherwise on Linux you will find it in the distro's repos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is still few ways to do DNS poisoning, like modifying [host file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on your system, since system will look up records from host file before querying from DNS server. Besides, [Man in the middle attack](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwiZ8KCI_fzGAhWDJ5QKHQukCCc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMan-in-the-middle_attack&ei=fQO3Vdm9OIPP0ASLyKK4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEcj63guxukczuv0x8-32z40gavuQ&sig2=l0jt_y7ATHjxOSq6SbscFg) is also a famous way to poison your DNS records.

Actually what are you trying to do? If you are worrying about ISP is hijacking your DNS record and do redirection, there are some famous free DNS services provider like [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) or [Google public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) you may try first.